# install weblogic on VM with Solaris OS

Tags: weblogic, vmware, solaris

I stuck in install weblogic on my vm solaris. i try that

```
java -d64 -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
```

and i got an error

```
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.  DISPLAY environment variable not set.    Failed <<<<
```

Any solution for these error?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you want to do an graphical install of the system without having a X11 running. The error message is quite normal for such an situation.

You could:

1. Not running the installer in the graphical mode by doing a silent install (please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/doc.1211/e24492/silent.htm#WLSIG131 for information)
2. Install the nescessary package to have an X11 and stuff running in your VM with `pkg install solaris-desktop`. Then execute the java command again from the GUI . This obviously only works if you can get a the graphical output of the VM for example via VNC or other tools.
3. You could set the DISPLAY variable to an installed  X11 implementation. For example i use Xquartz on my Apple notebook. Then configure DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY correctly. Or you could simply log into the Solaris system with ssh -X  . I prefer the second one, as it does everything automatically.

Comment: Have you set the DISPLAY variable ?